# Doxygen and sort of undocumented base class

Tags: c++, doxygen

Using Doxygen, I have some cases of C++ classes that publicly inhert from base classes that provide public members that I want documented on inherted subclass.  I don't actually want the base class in the documentation because it isn't directly part of the user interface.

For example

```cpp
class Base {
   int value_;
public:
   Base(int value) : value_(value) {}

   /// Returns the value to use
   int getValue() const { return value_; }
};

/// This is a class that is in the public user interface
class Derived : public Base {
   int more_data_;

public:
   /// @param value The value that many classes store
   /// @param data The data for this class
   Derived(int value, int data)
      : Base(value), more_data_(data)
   {}

   /// returns the additional data
   int getData() const { return more_data_; }
};
```

In the above example, I would like `Derived` to be documented as if all of the methods were defined in this class.

*In general*, when a base class is part of the public interface I don't want to repeat that documentation in the subclass, so for the project I have `INLINE_INHERITED_MEMB = NO`, but I would like *this* class to inline inherit members with no documented reference
to the base class.

Is this within my power?

Comment: Which version of doxygen do you use? I don't think this is in your power.

Comment: @albert Currently using 1.9.4

Comment: The current doxygen version is 1.10.0, but here it also won't be in your power.